# calling a function and setting it equal to a struct

Tags: c++, syntax

Could someone explain what is going on in line 12? how can I set a function equal to a struct (matrix);

```
mat4& getCurrentMatrix() { 
    if(currentMatrixMode == MGL_PROJECTION) {
         return projMatrix;
    }
    else { //Not sure if we need to account for MGL_TEXTURE or MGL_COLOR 
           //yet
        return modelViewMatrix;
    }
}

void setCurrentMatrix(mat4 matrix) {
    getCurrentMatrix() = matrix; //what is going on in here?
```

}

Comment: you're assigning an object to another object. It does something useful because the function returns a reference on some global/higher scope object.

Comment: so either projMatrix or ModelViewMatrix will be set to the input parameter matrix in setCurrentMatrix? For clarification, both modelViewMatrix and projMatrix are global structs.

Answer (score 2):

you're not setting a function equal to some other object, you're assigning the *result* of a function to another object.

If the function returns some object or value (but no reference), it has no useful effect (unless `=` operator is overridden with side effect!), for instance in C language.

But in C++, you can return a *reference* of a global/higher scope object

It does something useful because the function returns a reference on some global/higher scope object so it's equivalent to:

```
modelViewMatrix = matrix;
```

or

```
projMatrix = matrix;
```

depending on the parameter of the function

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked the & at the beginning of the function. I'm assuming this allows for this.

Answer (score 0):

The `getCurrentMatrix` function returns a reference to a `mat4`. It is the `mat4` that reference refers to that is being set equal to the matrix passed to the function.